# PHP Array increase a value during loop

Tags: php, arrays

The following code need to increase 2,9 during 10 times to achieve 27 in total. 
my code is just increase 2,9 every time and not respect the difference in the last item on array how can I solve it ? thank you.

result of the following code:

```
    Array ( [0] => 2.9 [1] => 5.8 [2] => 8.7 [3] => 11.6 [4] => 14.5 [5] => 17.4 [6] => 20.3 [7] => 23.2 [8] => 26.1 [9] => 29 )

.
```

and it should be:

```
 Array ( [0] => 2.9 [1] => 5.8 [2] => 8.7 [3] => 11.6 [4] => 14.5 [5] => 17.4 [6] => 20.3 [7] => 23.2 [8] => 26.1 [9] => 27 )

.
```

Code:

```
$horas_totais = 27;
$horario_dos_km = 9.3;
$getallours =[];
$rasteach = round( $horas_totais/$horario_dos_km, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
$tot='';
for($z=0;$z<=$horario_dos_km;$z++){
    $tot += $rasteach;
    $getallours[] = $tot;
}
$echo='<pre>';print_r($getallours);$echo='</pre>';
```

Comment: So should the last increment be ignored? Because 26.1 + 2.9 = 29, clearly. The fact that 2.9 is rounded up makes it so you can't reach exactly 27.

Comment: it shoul be ignored and replca in it place 27, that the point that i have no idea how can be handle. i have to receive it from calulation ond not just replace number 27

Comment: Welcome to 'real numbers (floating point numbers)'.  Everyone gets confused by this. see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Please go through it carefully. They will bite you. For example: You never test for real numbers to be equal! It will fail when you can see they are equal. ;-/ Never use them for money values! Never ever!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop up to the last but one occurrence, and then add your final value manually:

```
for ($z = 0; $z < $horario_dos_km - 1; $z++) {
  $tot += $rasteach;
  $getallours[] = $tot;
}
$getallours[] = $horas_totais;
```

Note that `$tot = '';` should be `$tot = 0;` (it does "work" with the empty string but should generate a warning).

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/D6pGQ**

Answer (score 0):

you can also use an if condition in the loop.

```
<?php
 $horas_totais = 27;
 $horario_dos_km = 9.3;
 $getallours = [];
 $rasteach = round($horas_totais / $horario_dos_km, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
 $tot = 0;
 for ($z = 0; $z < $horario_dos_km; $z++) {
    $tot += $rasteach;
    if($tot>27){
     $tot = 27;
    }
   $getallours[] = $tot;
 }

print_r($getallours);
```